# Characterization of the improper Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis

Sorry if this is a basic question; I'm just starting to learn measure theory.

In analysis, we have the following theorem:

> Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and let $S$ denote the discontinuity set of $f$. Then $f \in \mathcal R[a,b] \Longleftrightarrow \mu(S) = 0$

I was wondering whether or not this also applies to improper integrals of the form

$$\int_a^\infty f, \int_{\mathbb{R}} f$$

For simplicity, consider only the first type of improper integral. We can have for any bounded, compact interval with $x>a$, $f:[a,x] \to \mathbb{R}$ have a discontinuity set with measure $0$. This implies

$$g(x) := \int_a^x f$$ is well defined and letting $x \to \infty$ is valid, assuming the limit exists.

However, is it ever possible for

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \int_a^\infty f$$

to exist, but for

$$\mu(S_{[a,\infty)}) > 0$$?

If so, how do we characterize (improper) Riemann integrals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the sentence

> $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$ exists

you are assuming that $g(x)$ exists for all $x > a$ (for example). In particular, you know that $f\in \mathcal{R}[a,x]$ for any $x$. This means that $S_{[a,\infty)} \cap [a,x]$ has measure zero for any $x$.

Now, since $S_{[a,\infty)} = \cup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \left( S_{[a,\infty)} \cap [a,n]\right)$, it follows from the countable subadditivity property of the Lebesgue measure $\mu$ that the set of discontinuous points has measure zero.

---

That the Lebesgue criterion is usually stated only for *compact* intervals is that for improper integrals this is no longer if and only if. Clearly there are bounded continuous functions $f$ defined over $\mathbb{R}$ such that the integral implied by the notation $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f ~dx$ doesn't exist.